# How to blend images and aling them by center using CSS3 or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have two lists of images. Every image in the first list has a pair in the second. All images has the same size. Like this:

[image]
[image]

My task is to blend every pair of images and align them by center. Every image is transparent png, so it should drop a complex shadow.
[image]

The problem is, I don't fully understand how to do it.
For now I did it that way:

```
  .center
  {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 410px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .building-img
  {
    width: 600px;
    #background-color: #F8F8FF;
    #box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .route-img
  {
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    right: 304px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }  
  .filter-drop-shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    }


<div class="center">
            <img class="building-img filter-drop-shadow" src="img1.png" />
            <img class="route-img filter-drop-shadow" src="img2.png" />
</div>
```

Although it looks like it should work well, it does not. Because I used `position` attribute, images blend as I need, but they has a hidden areas which does not let me scale a web page without losing a center aligning.
So, is there any way to do it as I need? Blend images, drop shadow and align them by center.

Comment: If overlaid, each of the two images will have its own drop shadow. You won't get one drop-shadow for the "combined" image - at least, not with CSS drop-shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to position them via absolute.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aDqe.png" id="img1">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEdhL.png" id="img2">
```

CSS:

```
#img1 , #img2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it. But how should I align them by center then? And what if I had multiple number of those pairs, and they should go one by one.

Comment: If you put your position: absolute inside a div that is position: relative, and align that to the middle of the page, it conforms that the location that parent div lies in.